# PHP prevent form resubmittion on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently facing issues while preventing `F5` or `Refresh` event on browser to refresh my page.
Whenever user refreshes page code changed and resubmitted again. How to prevent that?

Here are my PHP Code :

```
<?php
include('include/dbConnect.php');

function handle_forget(){
    global $dbLink;

    $username = $_POST['userName'];
    $securityCode = $_POST['securityCode'];

    if(empty($securityCode) || empty ($username)){
        display_forget_form();
        return;
    }

    $forgetPass  = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_name = '$username' AND user_security_passcode = '$securityCode'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query ( $dbLink, $forgetPass) ; 

    if( $stmt === false){
        die (print_r (sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )){
        display_success_forget($username);
        return;
    }

    if( empty($row) ){
        display_failed_forget();
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt ( $stmt );
}


function display_success_forget($username){
    global $dbLink;

    echo 
    <<<SUCCESSFORM

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- start: HEAD -->
    <!-- start: HEAD -->
    <head>
        <title>TESTING</title>
        <!-- start: META -->
        <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge,IE=9,IE=8,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta content="" name="description" />
        <meta content="" name="author" />
        <!-- end: META -->
        <!-- start: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- end: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <!-- start: MAIN CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/themify-icons/themify-icons.min.css">
        <link href="vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="vendor/switchery/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!-- end: MAIN CSS -->
        <!-- start: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themes/theme-1.css" id="skin_color" />
        <!-- end: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <!-- end: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
    </head>
    <!-- end: HEAD -->
    <!-- start: BODY -->
    <body class="login">
        <!-- start: FORGOT -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="main-login col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="logo margin-top-30">
                    <center/><h3>Lembaga Tabung Angkatan Tentera CMS</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- start: FORGOT BOX -->
                <div class="box-forgot">
SUCCESSFORM;
                $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
                $randomString = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
                    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
                }

                $updatePassword = "UPDATE Users SET user_password = '$randomString' WHERE user_name = '$username'";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query ($dbLink, $updatePassword);
        echo
        <<<SUCCESSFORM1
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">

                        <h4 class="alert-heading margin-bottom-10"><i class="ti-close"></i> Warning!</h4>
                        <p class="margin-bottom-10">
                            *Please Keep Your Password Carefully.<br/><br/>
                            *Don't Share Your Password With Others. <br/><br/>
                            *You May Now Login With New Password.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Username: $username <br/><br/>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> New Password: $randomString
                </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-o" href="login.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Log-In
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- start: COPYRIGHT -->
                    <div class="copyright">
                        &copy; <span class="current-year"></span><span class="text-bold text-uppercase"> Xyreon Technology Sdn Bhd</span>. <span>All rights reserved</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end: COPYRIGHT -->
                </div>
                <!-- end: FORGOT BOX -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: FORGOT -->
        <!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/switchery/switchery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <!-- start: CLIP-TWO JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <!-- start: JavaScript Event Handlers for this page -->
        <script src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                Main.init();
                Login.init();
            });
        </script>
        <!-- end: JavaScript Event Handlers for this page -->
        <!-- end: CLIP-TWO JAVASCRIPTS -->
    </body>
    <!-- end: BODY -->
</html>
SUCCESSFORM1;

}

function display_failed_forget(){
    $phpself = $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"];
    echo 
    <<<FORGETFORM

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- start: HEAD -->
    <!-- start: HEAD -->
    <head>
        <title>TESTING</title>
        <!-- start: META -->
        <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge,IE=9,IE=8,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta content="" name="description" />
        <meta content="" name="author" />
        <!-- end: META -->
        <!-- start: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- end: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <!-- start: MAIN CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/themify-icons/themify-icons.min.css">
        <link href="vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="vendor/switchery/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!-- end: MAIN CSS -->
        <!-- start: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themes/theme-1.css" id="skin_color" />
        <!-- end: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <!-- end: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
    </head>
    <!-- end: HEAD -->
    <!-- start: BODY -->
    <body class="login">
        <!-- start: FORGOT -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="main-login col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="logo margin-top-30">
                    <center/><h3>Lembaga Tabung Angkatan Tentera CMS</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- start: FORGOT BOX -->
                <div class="box-forgot">
                    <form class="form-login" method="post" action="$phpself">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>
                                Forget Password?
                            </legend>
                            <p>
                                Enter your username & security passcode to reset password.
                            </p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                     Username <span class="symbol required"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Insert your Username" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    Security Passcode <span class="symbol required"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Insert your Security Code" class="form-control" id="securityCode" name="securityCode" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-o" href="login.php">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Log-In
                                </a>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                                    Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <!-- start: COPYRIGHT -->
                    <div class="copyright">
                        &copy; <span class="current-year"></span><span class="text-bold text-uppercase"> Xyreon Technology Sdn Bhd</span>. <span>All rights reserved</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end: COPYRIGHT -->
                </div>
                <!-- end: FORGOT BOX -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: FORGOT -->
        <!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/switchery/switchery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <!-- start: CLIP-TWO JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <!-- start: JavaScript Event Handlers for this page -->
        <script src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                Main.init();
                Login.init();
            });
        </script>
        <!-- end: JavaScript Event Handlers for this page -->
        <!-- end: CLIP-TWO JAVASCRIPTS -->
    </body>
    <!-- end: BODY -->
</html>
FORGETFORM;
}

function display_forget_form(){
    $phpself = $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"];
    echo 
    <<<FORGETFORM

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- start: HEAD -->
    <!-- start: HEAD -->
    <head>
        <title>TESTING</title>
        <!-- start: META -->
        <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge,IE=9,IE=8,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta content="" name="description" />
        <meta content="" name="author" />
        <!-- end: META -->
        <!-- start: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- end: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <!-- start: MAIN CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/themify-icons/themify-icons.min.css">
        <link href="vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="vendor/switchery/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!-- end: MAIN CSS -->
        <!-- start: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themes/theme-1.css" id="skin_color" />
        <!-- end: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <!-- end: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
    </head>
    <!-- end: HEAD -->
    <!-- start: BODY -->
    <body class="login">
        <!-- start: FORGOT -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="main-login col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="logo margin-top-30">
                    <center/><h3>Lembaga Tabung Angkatan Tentera CMS</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- start: FORGOT BOX -->
                <div class="box-forgot">
                    <form class="form-login" method="post" action="$phpself">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>
                                Forget Password?
                            </legend>
                            <p>
                                Enter your username & security passcode to reset password.
                            </p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                     Username <span class="symbol required"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Insert your Username" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    Security Passcode <span class="symbol required"></span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Insert your Security Code" class="form-control" id="securityCode" name="securityCode" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-o" href="login.php">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Log-In
                                </a>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                                    Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <!-- start: COPYRIGHT -->
                    <div class="copyright">
                        &copy; <span class="current-year"></span><span class="text-bold text-uppercase"> Xyreon Technology Sdn Bhd</span>. <span>All rights reserved</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end: COPYRIGHT -->
                </div>
                <!-- end: FORGOT BOX -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: FORGOT -->
        <!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/switchery/switchery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <!-- start: CLIP-TWO JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <!-- start: JavaScript Event Handlers for this page -->
        <script src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                Main.init();
                Login.init();
            });
        </script>
        <!-- end: JavaScript Event Handlers for this page -->
        <!-- end: CLIP-TWO JAVASCRIPTS -->
    </body>
    <!-- end: BODY -->
</html>
FORGETFORM;
}


$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if($method =="POST"){
    handle_forget();
}
else{
    display_forget_form();
}

?>
```

the `display_success_forget` function always been called if user refresh the page and the password renewed, I wanted to prevent that, anyway to do so? i had try to search for Redirect function but it need to have 2 pages to do so. Any other solution to prevent user to resubmit my form? Thanks.

Comment: Record what you need to keep in $_SESSION variables so you can display it in your script even if user refreshes

Comment: Redirecting seems the obvious solution, but I don't know what *i had try to search for Redirect function but it need to have 2 pages to do so* means.

Comment: @xNeyte Hi, did you mean i have to do something like this? $_SESSION = "$variable" ?

Comment: @jeroen What i mean is that Refirect have to direct to other page after finish processing, but what i want is that all my process progress in one php file only. Example: Page1.php finish all process then redirect to Page2.php to display result. But what i want is all the process and result is show in Page1.php only. Get it now?

Comment: You could store the data in a session, then redirect the page to itself and then display the data from the session? (remember to unset the session when /after you have displayed the data)

Comment: So redirect to the same page, you are checking for the method so it will not be resubmitted as it will not be `POST`.

Comment: You need to use header("Location:index.php"); function to redirect at last. This will resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a unique value to `$_SESSION` to prevent resubmitting the form. Add this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__req" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo rand(100000,999999); ?>" />
```

base on your script, other user can post anything and run your function! Change your php scripts like this:

```
<?php
    $method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    if($method =="POST"){
        if($_POST['key'] != $_SESSION['form_key'] && $_POST['__req']){  
            $_SESSION['form_key'] = $_POST['key'];
            handle_forget();
        }
        else{
            display_forget_form();
        }
    }
    else{
        display_forget_form();
    }   
?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the suggesstion i had manage to solve the problem by redirect the form to another page after the process finish. And i think your answer is reasonable so i mark it as answer. :) Have a good day ahead.

Comment: Hi Eng, i had try to implmenet the code u suggest but it seem like not working through.

Comment: There is no error, but i still can refresh and my "passcode" still can changed upon refresh. Example, when my proccess generate a passcode "123456", and user press refresh again the process generate another passcode "567890". I wanted to prevent that to happen.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\LTAT\login_forgot.php on line 415

Comment: i checked your code, shouldn't have problem. Add `session_start();` at top of PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

After your intitial postback, use something like the following the redirect the user back to the original page without POST variables:

```
if(empty($securityCode) || empty ($username)){
    display_forget_form();
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```